# React - Audio Player mp3 source file

Tags: reactjs

REACT Proof of concept work, trying to play an MP3 sound byte. I found an example in the answer portion of a Stack Overflow entry but it uses a URL for the sound byte. I'm looking to use a mp3 file stored under the React src folder.

Here's a link to the code that I was using. Please look at the code found in the Answer section.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/525803617355276/

I'd like to be able to use a file that is part of the React project instead of linking to a sound byte stored elsewhere.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your link seems to be broken.

If I get you right, you want to play a sound file in a react app. A possible approach would be to reference a mp3 file in an `<audio />` element via a relative path.

In a brief google search this tutorial popped up: https://medium.com/@jerrysbusiness/playing-a-sound-file-in-a-react-project-bd0ad079ad93.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Made the change to import the soundfile from the file location (as noted in the tutorial) and updated the URL tag to map directly to the soundfile instead of the url  that I was using and it worked correctly. Thanks Konstantin.